# Trying to get all the words from 10fastfingers test with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm practicing selenium and python trying to complete the typing test in 10fastfingers
I can see all of the words in "Inspect" but when I try it in code it only completes the words I can see in the first tab,
Any help ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(url='https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english')
time.sleep(2)
# Denied Privacy something..
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonDecline"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
test1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'words')
print(test1.text)
words = test1.text.split()

for word in words:
    input_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="inputfield"]')
    input_box.send_keys(word)
    input_box.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```

Getting success with the first window (first few words), in words theres only the first words as well so the problem is with getting all of them using: test1 = "driver.find_element(By.ID, 'words')"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to get actual text elements and loop into them.

Here is the example after you accepted consent

```js
words = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'words').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'span')
input_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'inputfield')

for word in words:
    input_box.send_keys(word.text)
    input_box.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
```